# The method setText string is undefined for the type view

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-edittext

I'm new to android and have have an assignment to create an email application. So I have 2 layouts and 2 activities, one for reading the email and one for writing the email. I'm trying to retain the information sent in the fields in the email writing activity for when the email is being read. The problem is at the **bolded line below -  "The method setText string is undefined for the type view", and I need to get all the text view to contain the information send from the other activity. I can post the other files if its needed, all help appreciated. I have tried other ways to assign the variable to text view but can't seem to get it to work.

DisplayMessageActivity.java

```
    package com.example.project;

    import com.example.project.R.layout;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        // Get the messages from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String messageto2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        String messagefrom2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
        String messagecc2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE3);
        String messagebcc2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE4);
        String messagesubject2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE5);
        String messagebody2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE6);



        **TextView msgto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.to2).setText(messageto2);**
        TextView msgfrom = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.from2);
        TextView msgcc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cc2);
        TextView msgbcc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bcc2);
        TextView msgsubject = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.subject2);
        TextView msgbody = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.body2);



    }

    /**
     * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private void setupActionBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
            // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
            // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
            // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
            //
            // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
            //
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

     }
```

TIA

Comment: All the below provided answers are absolutely correct. Please mark accepted if your problem got solved.

Comment: I have to wait 10 minutes or so before i can accept. I have 2 minutes left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods are resolved according to the static type of the reference. `findViewById()` is declared with a return type of `View` and since the class `View` doesn't declare a method `setText()`, the compiler complains. Use this

```
TextView msgto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.to2);
msgto.setText(messageto2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to change this:

```
(TextView)findViewById(R.id.to2).setText(messageto2);
```

to

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.to2)).setText(messageto2);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.to2)).setText(messageto2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView msgto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.to2).setText(messageto2);
```

Need to be changed to

```
TextView msgto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.to2);
msgto.setText(messageto2);
```

That should help.

Comment: Thanks that works fine, will have to give accept to Sotirios as he got there first:)